# VBA to find the last row and select the range from next cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have created this using record macro. The no of line differs everyday. so i want to find the last active cell in T column and go to the same cell V column. Then V:Z select range from down to up and fill down the formula which is available in V2.

```
Range("T3").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range("V2911":"Z2911").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select)
Selection.Special Cells(xlcellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.FillDown
```

> Range("V2911":"Z2911")

This one will always change.

In U also i have data but its not available for all the cells.

Comment: `range("V" & ws.usedrange.rows.count & ":z" & ws.usedrange.rows.count)`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav `Range("V2911":"Z2911")` shall remove this and add your code??

Comment: at least try :) yes, but change ws to activesheet by the looks of it from your code.  cheers, have a good weekend.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav its not working... got error called "Invalid Property"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly overkill...

```
Sub x()

Dim n As Long

n = Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("V2").Copy Range("V2:Z" & n)

End Sub
```

Comment: could you please tell me where i have to add this code. i have create using record macro..

Comment: Just try replacing all your current code with this.